# Can't update 4 NuGet packages due to error "Could not find a part of the path..."

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I can't update any/all of the following packages in my solution:

[image]

I get the error:

[image]

I've tried reinstalling all packages via NuGet console but still get the same error.

I'm using VS 2022 64bit v 17.0.4.  Migrating to PackageReference isn't allowed on this solution.

Comment: It's weird that forward and backward slashes are mixed in the file path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only workaround for us was to clone the solution from the remote repository to a fresh local directory.

We tried emptying the `NuGet` cache, but without success. The problem is that the `.dll`-File was not present in the package directory (see file path from OP). Mixed backward and forward slashes are not a problem. Deleting/restoring packages did not solve the issue. Commands like `Get-Package` didn't work either.

We tried diffing the two folders, a) the freshly cloned working one and b) the old not working one, as we suspected that config files not under version control caused the issue. But without any success. We couldn't find any relevant difference. The binary .suo-File was not considered by us. Deleting the .suo-File and restoring packages didn't solve the issue either.

We gave up on that point because we have a workaround to deal with this issue.
I would dig for global VS/NuGet cache/setting files but we decided to not invest more time on that.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and as you wrote that copying repository to fresh local directory worked for you, I made some tests.

I have figured it out, that the problem is windows's path lengt limitation to 260 characters.

[Maximum Path Length Limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry)

Comment: This solved the issue for me. Thanks! I was building on a MacOS machine and when I moved to a Windows machine I had the error; the path limitation was the issue and once I moved to a shorter path it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I also tried to disable path limiting but it won't work (I install manually NuGet packages at runtime using official api), but actually, when I made the path smaller (about ~230 letters) it started working fine!

Answer (score 1):

By referencing these [Nuget Official Site](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions/) and [.Net Standard Implementation Support Chart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support), .Net 4.6.1 is compatible with NetStandard2.0 Applications.

Please check the version compatibility from the above references and try installing the required dependencies.